# Dispatcher, Tasks and cancellation issues

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am writing a library to automate internet explorer.  The library sets up its own message loop by starting a thread and using Dispatcher.Run.  The reason for this is to keep internet explorer and mshtml on the same thread.

I then use the following in the library.

```
    Private ExDispatcher As Dispatcher
    Private Success As Boolean
    Private EXThreadWaiter As Threading.AutoResetEvent

    Public Async Function ClickAndWaitForNewPageAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)


        Return Await Task.Run(Of Boolean)(Function()

                                              ExDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, Sub() startClickAndWaitForNewPage())

                                              EXThreadWaiter.WaitOne()

                                              Debug.Print("Completed with: " + Success.ToString)
                                              Return Success

                                          End Function)
    End Function

    Private Sub startClickAndWaitForNewPage()

        'do a lot of stuff and wait for internet explorer

        'if we are happy and all good set Success = True
        'now let the thread in the task go
        EXThreadWaiter.Set()

    End Sub
```

ClickAndWaitForNewPageAsync starts a task which is on a new thread, it immediately then uses my message loop to call startClickAndWaitForNewPage and all the Internet Explorer stuff is done.  When everything is ok the variable Success is set to a value and EXThreadWaiter.Set() is called which releases the task thread and the result is returned.

A client of this library therefore uses it as shown below.

```
 Private Async Sub someFunction()

        Dim res As Boolean = Await ClickAndWaitForNewPageAsync()

        If res Then
            'continue on with code
        Else
            'do nothing
        End If

    End Sub
```

The issue I have with this is how to shutdown or stop my library which needs to happen for various reasons. I currently have this method in the same class as ClickAndWaitForNewPageAsync

```
Public Sub StopIt()

        Success = False
        EXThreadWaiter.Set()

    End Sub
```

This method sets Success to False and lets the task continue.  This mostly works fine but it is possible that the following happens.

1. startClickAndWaitForNewPage sets Success to True
2. EXThreadWaiter.Set() is called
3. Debug.Print("Completed with: " + Success.ToString) indicates Success is True
4. StopIt() runs setting Success = False
5. someFunction in the client code receives Success = True

This means that in someFunction it continues with its code thinking everything is ok but in fact it is not.

How can I prevent this from happening?

By the way the Cancellation Token etc i do not think will help, but I'm happy to hear differently.

**What I previously used**
I previously did not use Tasks.  I would simply use the Dispatcher begininvoke which would mean everything is done on the right thread and the client would have to subscribe to an event that would fire when everything was done successfully.  This felt untidy to me and thus I am trying this new method.

Comment: You don't show the relevant parts of startClickAndWaitForNewPage. In your case the question is when "return success" happens. As step 3b or step 4b. That makes a difference in what someFunction in the client will see as the result.

Comment: I have just made up this example for my question. startClickAndWaitForNewPage might start a timer and continually check for a HTMLtag to appear, when it does appear it clicks it and then again waits for Internet explorer to navigate. Once the navigation is successful then it would set Success and call EXThreadWaiter.Set()

Comment: @darbid: Since you need a separate STA thread, I think using `Dispatcher` directly is appropriate. If you want to avoid events, use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` instead.